# Solving the Recurrence Relation/Series fn = 1 + fn-1*(M) where M is a constant

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, recursion, recursive-algorithms

So I'm trying to solve this week's [FiveThirtyEight Riddler](http://fivethirtyeight.com/features/can-you-solve-this-elevator-button-puzzle/).

> In a building’s lobby, some number (N) of people get on an elevator
>   that goes to some number (M) of floors. There may be more people than
>   floors, or more floors than people. Each person is equally likely to
>   choose any floor, independently of one another. When a floor button is
>   pushed, it will light up.
>
> What is the expected number of lit buttons when the elevator begins
>   its ascent?

I think I'm close, but I'm having trouble solving the following recurrence relation. I got the following equation to find the expected number of lit buttons in a given building of M floors and N people.

> f<sub>n</sub> = 1 + f<sub>n-1</sub>*(1- 1/M)

f<sub>n</sub> is the expected number of lit up buttons for a given N & M. M is some constant, so the quantity (1- 1/M) is essentially a constant. I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction to solve such a series.

Additionally, I simulated the problem in R, and the formula above seemed to match the simulation. However, if you see something wrong, please let me know.

I also thought that my equation right now include the top floor elevator light, but in the puzzle that light actually won't be pressed. So could I just subtract that constant 1 from my equation, making the formula a simple geometric series?

Comment: $$f_n-M=\left(1-\frac1M\right)\cdot(f_{n-1}-M)\implies f_n-M=\left(1-\frac1M\right)^n\cdot(f_{0}-M)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We first convert from non-homogeneous to homogeneous:
$$
f_n = c f_{n-1} + 1
$$
with $c = 1 - 1/M$. This means
$$
f_{n-1} = c f_{n-2} + 1
$$
and for the difference
$$
f_n - f_{n-1} = c (f_{n-1}- f_{n-2}) \iff \\
f_n = (c +1) f_{n-1} - c f_{n-2}
$$
and for this we can use the usual algorithm: The characteristic polynomial is
$$
p(t) = t^2 - (c+1) t + c
$$
with roots $r_1$, $r_2$: 
$$
0 = (t - (c+1)/2))^2 + c - (c+1)^2/4 \iff \\
\frac{c^2 - 2c + 1}{4} = \left( t - \frac{c+1}{2} \right)^2 \iff \\
t = \frac{c+1 \pm \sqrt{c^2-2c + 1}}{2}
$$
and solution
$$
f_n = k_1 r_1^n + k_2 r_2^n
$$
The constants $k_1$, $k_2$ have to be determined from initial conditions, e.g.:
$$
f_1 = k_1 r_1 + k_2 r_2 \\
f_2 = k_1 r_1^2 + k_2 r_2^2
$$

Answer (score 0):

If one person gets in one button will be lit however many floors (though you may as well assume $M\ge 2$) $f_1=1$

Put $K=1-\frac{1}{M}$, then:
$$
\begin{aligned}
f_1&=1\\
f_2&=1+K\\
f_3&=1+K(1+K)=1+K+K^2\\
\vdots\\
f_n&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}K^k=\frac{K^n-1}{K-1}
\end{aligned}
$$